# matlab: how to print string and variable inline

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab.

I am used to python. In python i generally do the below to print text and string together

```
a=10
b=20
print("a :: "+str(a)+" :: b :: "+str(b))
```

In matlab we have to use sprintf and use formats. But is this python kind of printing possible in matlab with any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of MATLAB R2016b you can [write](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/converting-from-numeric-to-string.html):

```
disp("a :: "+string(a)+" :: b :: "+string(b)))
```

You can also use the concatenation operator `'[]'`:

```
disp (['a :: ' num2str(a) ' :: b :: ' num2str(b)])
```

The first example uses the [`string array`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) while the second uses [`character array`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html).

Comment: You don't even need the explicit `string(...)` conversions. Most types will automatically be converted to strings when you do `"some string" + x`. So `disp("a :: " + a + " :: b :: " + b)` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use disp function to print and num2str to convert number to string

```
disp (['a :: ' num2str(a) ' :: b :: ' num2str(b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using formatted print(fprintf) you can do that:

```
name = 'Alice';   
age = 12;
fprintf('%s will be %d this year.\n',name,age);
```

Also you can use `disp` command.